# I try to start a service when the GPS turned on

Tags: android, service, gps, broadcastreceiver

I'm new on android developing. I need to make a service to start when gps activated.

That's what I've done so far:

service:

```
public class MainService extends Service implements LocationListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;
Intent i;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 1, this);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    String msg = "New Latitude: " + location.getLatitude()
            + "New Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();


    Log.d("",msg);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.i("", "------------------->GPS is off");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    Log.i("", "------------------->Gps is turned on!! ");

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class GPSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("", "Receiver is on");
    if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
        // react on GPS provider change action
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MainService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver
        android:name="gr.dit.hua.it21370.gpsreciever.GPSReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="gr.dit.hua.it21370.gpsreciever.MainService"
        android:process=":gps_service">
    </service>
</application>
```

I've tried and I've searched a lot but I didn't manage to fix it.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Remove `android:exported="false"` (as you specifically *need* this receiver to be exported). Beyond that, you might explain what "I didn't manage to fix it" means.

Comment: Try new fused location api provided by Google play service. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

Comment: @ΒΑΣΙΛΗΣ ΧΑΡΛΑΥΤΗΣ: what is issue? its working, not working?

Comment: @Dhawal Sodha Parmar totaly not working. The broadcaster never starts and due to this reason neither the service